# JPanel changing colors to draw with mouse

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, java-2d

I am trying to use `JPanel` to paint on the canvas using the mouse. So far everything works fine. I can draw. and I can set the color to be whatever I choose. However I am trying to make it so that when I click a button, it changes the color to whatever the button is attached to.

Like if I draw with black, then hit the "Blue" button, it changes to blue instead of black...I'm not sure on where I'm going wrong though. Heres my `paintComponent` part.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == button1)
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
    });

    for (Point point : points)
        g.fillOval(point.x, point.y, 4 , 4);
}
```

Comment: A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, no, no. Why are you adding a `ActionListener` to a button inside a paint method?  The paint method could be called a dozen times in quick succession by the repaint manager, now you have a dozen or more `ActionListener`s registered to the button .. which aren't going to do anything.

Start by creating a field which can store the desired paint color.  Register a `ActionListener` to your buttons, probably via the classes constructor, which change the "paint color" and trigger a new paint cycle.  When `paintComponent` called, apply the desired paint color

```
private Color paintColor = Color.BLACK;

protected void setupActionListener() {
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == button1) {
                paintColor = Color.BLUE;
                repaint();
            }
        }
    });    
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(paintColor);
    for (Point point : points)
        g.fillOval(point.x, point.y, 4 , 4);


}
```

Now, go and read [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to gain a better understand into how painting actually works in Swing

Comment: Thank you! This helped a ton! Im sure my obvious noob java skills showed...lol

Comment: Can I ask one more question? This method you gave worked great, but how would I make it so that whatever has already been drawn, doesn't get changed when the new color is changed?

Like if I draw in blue, then change to red to draw, I'd like the blue drawing to still be there. But instead all of it changes to red.

Comment: This a larger question - you have two basic options.  Either you record the color used when capturing the points, wrapping them in a custom object OR you paint to a backing buffer, like a `BufferedImage` and then paint this I the `paintComponent` method

Comment: Okay thank you! I'll look into those. Thanks again for the help!